# GNU gcc compiler cannot handle partial include statements

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, gnu-make

Imagine that I have a C-project in the following folder:

`C:\microcontroller\stm32\myProject`

I have two important folders inside myProject:
 `- source` => here are all my `.c` and `.h` files 
 `- build`  => gcc will write all the object files in here

Note: as you can see, the backward slashes indicate that this is happening on a Windows pc.

The figure below gives an overview:

[image]

I will not display my complete makefile here, because that would lead us too far. The rules inside the makefile for all `.c` => `.o` files are similar.  Let us just focus on the compilation of one specific file: `fileA2.c`:

```
--------------------- COMPILATION OF FILE fileA2.c -------------------

Building ./build/folderA/fileA2.o

arm-none-eabi-gcc C:\\microcontroller\\stm32\\myProject\\source\\folderA\\fileA2.c
               -o C:\\microcontroller\\stm32\\myProject\\build\\folderA\\fileA2.o
               -c
               -MMD
               -mcpu=cortex-m7
               -...
               -IC:/microcontroller/stm32/myProject/source/folderA
               -IC:/microcontroller/stm32/myProject/source/folderB
```

Notice that the gcc call ends with two include flags: one for folderA and one for folderB. This enables gcc to use any of the header files from these folders (`fileA1.h`, `fileA2.h` or `fileB1.h`) if `fileA2.c` has an import statement.

Let us now consider the source code in `fileA2.c`. We assume that this file needs to include `fileA2.h` and also `fileB1.h`.

```
/*******************************/
/* SOURCE CODE fileA2.c        */
/*******************************/

// Some include statements
#include "fileA2.h"
#include "fileB1.h"

// Code
...
```

These include statements work perfectly. The gcc compiler retrieves the files `fileA2.h` and `fileB1.h` in the given folders. But I noticed that the following does not work:

```
/*******************************/
/* SOURCE CODE fileA2.c        */
/*******************************/

// Some include statements
#include "fileA2.h"
#include "folderB/fileB1.h"

// Code
...
```

The last include statement is a 'partial path' to the file. I get the error when compiling:
`fatal error: folderB/fileB1.h: No such file or directory`

How can I get gcc to handle this?

PS: It is not my own habit to use 'partial paths'. But they appear a lot in the libraries from the silicon vendor of my chip, so I have to live with it.

Comment: as `fileA2.c` is in `folderA` and no `folderB` is inside `folderA`, that's the reason of not finding the include file.  Just try `#include "../folderB/fileB1.h" and it will find it normally.  This means go to parent directory, then to `folderB`, and finally include the file `fileB1.h` there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You specify two paths to look for includes other than the current directory for the source file:

```
           -IC:/microcontroller/stm32/myProject/source/folderA
           -IC:/microcontroller/stm32/myProject/source/folderB
```

You get the error because neither
`C:/microcontroller/stm32/myProject/source/folderA/folderB/fileB1.h` nor
`C:/microcontroller/stm32/myProject/source/folderB/folderB/fileB1.h` exists.

To address the error, you can add the following path:

```
           -IC:/microcontroller/stm32/myProject/source
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me a lot :-)

Answer (score 3):

When using double-quotes to include a header file the compiler first looks in the same directory as the current file. If the header file is not found then it continues with the standard include search paths.

So when the compiler compiles the file `source/folderA/fileA2.c` the first directory the compiler will look for include files is the `source/folderA` directory. In the first example the `fileB1.h` will not be found there, but since you added `source/folderB` to the standard search path it will be found there as `source/folderB/fileB2.h`.

In the second example there is no `folderB/fileB1.h` file on `source/folderA` so the compiler will search the standard search path. When it comes to `source/folderB` it will again try `folderB/fileB2.h` (i.e. `source/folderB/folderB/fileB2.h`) and it will still not be found, nor will it be found anywhere else.

You need to add `-IC:/microcontroller/stm32/myProject/source` to be able to find `folderB/fileB1.h`.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Your answer is also correct. Unfortunately I cannot mark both answers with the green checkmark. But be assured that I have appreciated your answer equally well ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Apart of the two correct responses you have received before this, you have the third chance to specify the path to the file in the `#include` directive *from the curren directory*, as with

```
`#include "../folderB/fileB1.h"
```